# Issue in Tizen Web Unit Test (TV App)

Tags: unit-testing, tizen, television

I have written a simple testcase for one of the Tizen TV sample app to run the Tizen Web Unit Test.
I have done the certificate registration along with adding the Emulator Device ID added into Distributor Certificate.
When i try to Run AS->Tizen Web Unit Test Application im getting the below issue.
Could someone pls help to resolve this issue?

```
step SDB shell handle failed
Failed to `step SDB shell handle 'mkdir -p /opt/usr/apps/tmp' command` operation
 (Return Code:31)sdb command rejected exception
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1**

Check sdb capability of the device.

a) Run cmd/terminal

b) Move to [SDK install Folder]\tools

c) Run command 'sdb capability' .

[image]

If you cannot see capability value of sdb, try updating your TV device software.

**Step-2**

Tizen Web project should be created from the template TV-(**latest version**)-Basic application(or else).

Try creating a new Tizen Web project from the correct template and assigned the required files to that project.

Thank you.